# I can't login to my own admin account in a laravel project. I KNOW the details are correct. Using Table Plus

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm doing a small project. I have a database that is meant to verify logins. I'm creating an Admin Account with my own email, I have the bog-standard error messages of:

- "Unregistered Email"
- "Password or Email Incorrect"
- "Missing Password"
  etc

When I enter JUST my email, my login page recognizes it and doesn't throw an error message (so I know it's accessing my database correctly).
When I enter my password, the login page declares the email or password is incorrect.

I know it's recognizing my email, so it's the password that's incorrect, but I also KNOW it's correct (I typed it manually into my Table Plus database.)

Images included below: (This bug is killing me, help would be EXTREMELY appreciated)

Email being recognized first picture.
My database entries second picture.
Third picture is showing my password not being accurate. In the picture the password is plain text, because I am trouble shooting.

- [Email Recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylzh7.jpg)
- [Password is wrong, even though it's clearly right!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeOLv.jpg)
- [example table entry where password is put as test5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFiLv.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a blank password stored in the database, this is a very dangerous approach and not recommended at all, you need to hash your passwords in order to login, I'm not sure what authentication you are using (ui/sanctum/breeze) but I recommend you use **laravel/breeze**, instead of building your own authentication using: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-blade

Once that is installed, you can simply modify the blade to look anyway you like it to look.

---

To **hash** a password to be stored correctly you can do the following:

**User Controller (Top Area):**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

**User Controller (store method example):**

```
/**
    * Store a newly created resource in storage.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'email' => ['required','email',Rule::unique('users')],
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
        
    $user = new User();
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->save();
        
    return redirect('somewhere');
}
```

**Note:** You may also opt for using `bcrypt($request->password)` to directly crypt the password without having to use `Hash::make();`

Comment: You're a saviour. I wish I could more than like a post. 

Yes this was the solution. Also I'm just trying to understand laravel more, so I wanted to make it on my own, and this was the only bug I ran into.

So again, thank you! 

P.S. Thanks for teaching me better practice!

Comment: @raining glad its working for you, if you liked the result, you may leave an upvote on my answer. Good luck and don't hesitate to ask further questions on stack overflow :)